# Angular2+rollupjs: "node_modules\rxjs-es\util\root.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rollupjs

I'm having trouble building my Angular2 app with Rollupjs, following the advice provided here:
http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

When doing "npm run rollup", rollupjs throws the above error. My setup is as follows:

rollup.config.js

```js
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
class RollupNG2 {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
  }
  resolveId(id, from) {
    if (id.startsWith('rxjs/')) {
      return `${__dirname}/node_modules/rxjs-es/${id.replace('rxjs/', '')}.js`;
    }
  }
}

const rollupNG2 = (config) => new RollupNG2(config);

export
default {
  entry: 'src/main.js',
  sourceMap: true,
  moduleName: 'main',
  plugins: [
    rollupNG2(),
    nodeResolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true
    }),
    commonjs({ // https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs
      exclude: ['node_modules/@angular/**', 'node_modules/rxjs-es'],
      ignoreGlobal: false,
      sourceMap: false,
    })
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "Public Transit App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "build": "tscg",
    "clean": "rmdir /S /Q dist",
    "minify": "uglifyjs dist/bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/bundle.min.js",
    "rollup": "rollup -f iife -c -o dist/bundle.es2015.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-3",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-3",
    "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-3",
    "@angular2-material/list": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
    "@vaadin/angular2-polymer": "^1.0.0-beta2",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "modernizr": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.5",
    "node-fetch": "^1.5.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "rxjs-es": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup": "^0.34.13",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^4.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^3.14.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typescript-with-globs": "^0.1.4",
    "typings": "^1.3.3"
  }
}
```

The entire project (such as it is) is here:
https://github.com/evelbulgroz/public-transit-app-rc52

Kinda new to this, so not sure if I'm missing something obvious? And pretty stuck, so any help is highly appreciated.